# IntegerList help in Java

Tags: java, arrays

So in class we follow the lab manual instructions. I was able to do step one and two, I just need help with step three.

---

Lab Manuel Instructions:

3. Add a method void removeFirst(int newVal) to the IntegerList class that removes the first occurrence of a value from the list. If the value does not appear in the list, it should do nothing (but it’s not an error). Removing an item should not change the size of the array, but note that the array values do need to remain contiguous, so when you remove a value you will have to shift everything after it down to fill up its space. Also remember to decrement the variable that keeps track of the number of elements.

Add an option to the menu in IntegerListTest to test your new method.

---

### IntegerList

```
public class IntegerList
{
    private int count;
    private double totalInt;
    int[] list; //values in the list
    //-------------------------------------------------------
    //create a list of the given size
    //-------------------------------------------------------

    void addElement(int newVal)
    {
        if (count == list.length)
            increaseSize();

        list[count] = newVal;
        count++;
    }

    void removeFirst(int newVal2)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length-1; i++)
        {
            if (newVal2 == list[i])
            {
                list[list.length] =  (Integer) null;
                list[i] = list [i-1];
            }
        }

    }

    public IntegerList(int size)



    {
        list = new int[size];
        count = 0;

    }

    public void randomize()
    {
        for (int i=0; i<list.length; i++)
            {
            list[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
            count++;
            }

    }
            public void print()
    {
        for (int i=0; i<count; i++)
            System.out.println(i + ":\t" + list[i]);
    }




private void increaseSize()
{
    int[] temp = new int[list.length * 2];

    for (int lst = 0; lst < list.length; lst++)
        temp[lst] = list[lst];

    list = temp;
}
}
```

### **IntegerListTest**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class IntegerListTest
{
    static IntegerList list = new IntegerList(10);
    static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        printMenu();
        int choice = scan.nextInt();
        while (choice != 0)
        {
            dispatch(choice);
            printMenu();
            choice = scan.nextInt();
        }
    }
```

public static void dispatch(int choice)
    {

```
int loc;
switch(choice)
{
case 0:
    System.out.println("Bye! ") ;
    break;
case 1:
    System.out.println("How big should the list be?");
    int size = scan.nextInt();
    list = new IntegerList(size);
    list.randomize();
    break;
case 2:
    list.print();
    break;
case 3:
    System.out.println("What number would you like to add?");
    int newVal = scan.nextInt();
    list.addElement(newVal);
    break;
case 4:
    System.out.println("What number do you want to remove? (Removes first occurance.)");
    int newVal2 = scan.nextInt();
    list.removeFirst(newVal2);
default:
    System.out.println("Sorry, invalid choice");
}
}


public static void printMenu()
{
    System.out.println("\n Menu ");
    System.out.println(" ====");
    System.out.println("0: Quit");
    System.out.println("1: Create a new list (** do this first!! **)");
    System.out.println("2: Print the list");
    System.out.println("3: Add to the list");
    System.out.println("4: Remove Integer");
    System.out.print("\nEnter your choice: ");
        }
    }
```

---

Any help is greatly appreciated. It would be cool if you could also explain why so I can learn from this. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can loop the array to find the first element that matches a given value.
If it is found, save its position to index and shift all elements after it by one position:

```
void removeFirst(int newVal2) {
  int index = -1;
  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
     if (index == -1 && newVal2 == list[i]) {
       // element found - save index
       index = i;
     }
     if (index != -1) {
        // this code handles after found case
        if (i == count-1) {
          // zero-out last element
          list[i] = 0;
          count--;
        }
        else {
          // shift value
          list[i] = list[i+1];
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void removeFirst(int val){
    //the position at which the algorithm currently is
    int i = 0;

    boolean found = false;

    //search for the first occurence of val in the array
    for(; i < count && list[i] != val ; i++);
    //i is now the index of the first value equal to val in list

    //if a match was found, the index must be smaller than the array-size
    found = (i < count);

    //shift all elements that are right of the value to the left
    //to leave no empty space. Since the value at i is the searched value  
    //it's left out (i += 1)
    i += 1;
    for(; i < count ; i++)
        list[i - 1] = list[i];//move the current element one to the left

    //check if a match was found and decrement the sizecounter, if one was found
    if(found)
        --count;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was getting nervous because I couldn't figure it out and it was for my Computer Science class. :)

Answer (score 0):

i don't really have time to give u much details and i know this is not really an efficient way, but what u could do is to always create a new array of "size-1" and then take note of the index of the array element you want to remove, then copy everything before and after that array element into your new array, once all of this is done you could copy it back into the original array like this oldArray = newArray.